# Format of an Azure Dev Ops Web URL to create new work item

Tags: url, azure-devops, hyperlink

Is there a way to modify the URL for creation of a new work item to include parameters for specific field values? For example, if I want to have a link where a user can click to create a new bug and have it auto-populate the title or the AssignedTo value. I have the base [https://dev.azure.com/cseng/\](https://dev.azure.com/cseng/%5C)<PROJECT NAME>/_workitems/create/Bug link, but looking for more.

The REST APIs might be the answer, but I am looking for something someone could click in a browser or PowerBI report and be taken to a browser window for bug creation.

So far, if I just create something like this: [https://dev.azure.com/cseng/\](https://dev.azure.com/cseng/%5C)<PROJECT NAME>/_workitems/create/Bug&Title='TEST', I just get a server error message saying "Invalid argument value. Parameter name: typeNames"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on workitem templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#define-an-unplanned-work-item-template-using-a-hyperlink) shows workitem from ad-hoc template creation by using URLs in the following format:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_workItems/create/Task?
[System.Title]=TaskTitle&
[System.AssignedTo]=Someone&
[System.Description]=<p>Some+description.</p>&
[System.Tags]=FeatureA&
[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity]=Development&
[System.IterationPath]=Fabrikam+Fiber%5CIteration+1
```